# Why the pointer transfered is not the expected value in FFI?

Tags: haskell, ffi

I try to call a *C* function with the declaration from Haskell side:

```c
int IupOpen(int *argc, char ***argv);
```

Then I do the following binding:

```hs
foreign import capi "iup.h IupOpen"
    c_IupOpen :: Ptr CInt -> Ptr (Ptr CString) -> IO CInt
iupOpen :: Maybe [String]   -- ^ Program's command line arguments
        -> IO Int      -- ^ The initialization status flag
iupOpen args = case args of
    Nothing -> fromIntegral <$> c_IupOpen nullPtr nullPtr
    Just argv -> alloca $ \argcPtr -> do
        poke argcPtr (fromIntegral . length $ argv)
        argvs <- mapM (`withCString` return) argv
        pCstr <- withArray argvs return
        argvPtr <- alloca $ \ppCstr -> poke ppCstr pCstr >> return ppCstr
        fromIntegral <$> c_IupOpen argcPtr argvPtr
```

After compiling, the following warning is given:

```sh
C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc6096_0\ghc_5.c: In function 'ghczuwrapperZC1ZChiupzm0zi1zi0zi0zm1ddNNYbMeka1JTSCkHxKK2ZCGraphicsziIUPziRawziIupZCIupOpen':
C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc6096_0\ghc_5.c:10:143: warning: passing argument 2 of 'IupOpen' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   10 | HsInt32 ghczuwrapperZC1ZChiupzm0zi1zi0zi0zm1ddNNYbMeka1JTSCkHxKK2ZCGraphicsziIUPziRawziIupZCIupOpen(void* a1, void*** a2) {return IupOpen(a1, a2);}    
      |                                                                                                                                               ^~       
      |                                                                                                                                               |        
      |                                                                                                                                               void *** 
In file included from C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\ghc6096_0\ghc_5.c:7:
C:/.../hs/hs-iup/iup-3.30_Win64_mingw6_lib/include/iup.h:37:56: note: expected 'char ***' but argument is of type 'void ***'
   37 | IUP_API int       IupOpen          (int *argc, char ***argv);
```

But the parameter `argvPtr` I passed is really of type `Ptr (Ptr CString)`. I don't understand why this warning happens.

Thans for any ideas!

=======Update 1===========

After some tries, I solved the issue by replacing `capi` with `ccall`. It seems that `capi` have a procedure to produce some wrapper functions, which don't have the proper type signature.

But still I don't know why `capi` can't work correctly? Is it a bug or due to anything that I haven't noticed?

======Update 2=============

New code without dangling pointers (I believe ^_^):

```hs
foreign import capi "iup.h IupOpen"
    c_IupOpen :: Ptr CInt -> Ptr (Ptr CString) -> IO CInt
open :: Maybe [String]     -- ^ Program's command line arguments
     -> IO Int             -- ^ The initialization status flag
open args = case args of
    Nothing -> fromIntegral <$> c_IupOpen nullPtr nullPtr
    Just argv -> alloca $ \ptrArgc -> do
        poke ptrArgc (fromIntegral . length $ argv)
        alloca $ \ptrCStr -> do
            cstrArr <- mapM newCString argv   -- to free an array of pointer
            pokeArray ptrCStr cstrArr
            alloca $ \pptrCStr -> do
                poke pptrCStr ptrCStr
                flag <- c_IupOpen ptrArgc pptrCStr
                mapM_ free cstrArr
                return . fromIntegral $ flag
```

The pointer type is still mismatched unless using `ccall`.

=============Update 3=====================

Well, finally I find that it's a bug according to [the issue #15531](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/15531)

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes, you're right. It's a typo. It should be `argv`, and the warning remains.

Comment: Unrelated but important: be careful, ``(`withCString` return)`` will always return a dangling pointer! `withCString f` will free the C string as soon as `f` returns. You need to keep those strings alive for longer than that, use `newCString` and don't forget to free all the strings at the very end.

Comment: @chi Thanks for your tips! That's really the problem I missed. What about `mallocForeignPtr` for my case? it's cheaper and faster according to the [GHC notes](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/exts/ffi.html?highlight=capiffi#memory-allocation).

Comment: Maybe it should be OK, I guess. I don't remember the exact semantics of all these allocation routines. :-/

Comment: `argvPtr <- alloca $ \ppCstr -> poke ppCstr pCstr >> return ppCstr` - argvPtr is also dangling.

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I have found the problem.